# Ipython common problems

Tags: python, django, command-line, ipython

I love iPython's so many features, magic functions.

I recently upgraded to the latest 0.10 version. But I face following common problems:

- `%hist` one of the most frequently used magic functions, doesn't exist.
- `dreload` doesn't seems to work (works only for modules?).
- `run -d` for debugging doesn't work
- At times, typed characters are not displayed on the console*
- By default even the ? and ?? didn't work. I had to hack for that to work*

*The last 2 problems are true for the previous versions too.

I am on Ubuntu 9.04 with Python 2.6.2 and IPython 0.10

Comment: Should this be a community wiki? The thing that keeps me from using ipython is that the history you can select by hitting the arrow-up key is useless when you have defined a function. It just spits out an indentation error when you hit enter.

Comment: 4th problem is because terminal looses stdin. It can be recovered by executing "reset" in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like an issue with your particular setup.  ? and ?? have always worked on my machine, hist is still a magic function, and dreload has always only worked for modules--what else would it do?

as for the debug thing, it's a known issue with python 2.6: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+bug/381069